# NullPointerException: Cannot invoke FlashMap.addTargetRequestParam() because the return value of RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap() is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMap.addTargetRequestParam(String, String)" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)" is null
```

Класс `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` обрабатывает ошибки при отправке формы для входа на сайт (например, что имя пользователя занято):

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Перезагрузить страницу с формой  и отправить сообщение об ошибке,
        // используя флэш-атрибуты
        RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request).addTargetRequestParam("incorrectUsernameOrPassword", String.valueOf(true));
        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

Почему `RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request)` возвращает `null` и как органзивать эту логику правильно?